# Can't update my view pages at Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, view, browser-cache

How can I fix this problem. Please teach me how to solve this....

First, I had tried to use page cache on my web app. But, it doesn't run well. That was not so good. So, I updated to get rid of page cache. After that, my app's view page that had page cache could not be updated.

below is a my config/environment/development.rb

```
KaguShop::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Do not eager load code on boot.
  config.eager_load = false

  # Show full error reports and disable caching.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send.
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Raise an error on page load if there are pending migrations
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

  # Debug mode disables concatenation and preprocessing of assets.
  # This option may cause significant delays in view rendering with a large
  # number of complex assets.
  config.assets.debug = true

  #caching for objects
  #config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store
end
```

And, after I edited my cache setting, I tried this command.
※and of course, I reopen the browser.

```
rails console
Rails.cache.clear
```

Comment: Do you use pow rack server etc.?

Comment: Did you reload your server after changes in configuration?

Comment: No, I use only WEBrick

Comment: And what about cache methods in View?- did you remove them?

Comment: My cache method is a 'caces_page'. And I have already removed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OMG....
This is the answer of this question.
I didnt know this rails's structure...
[After removing caches_page cached sites are still not updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11520816/after-removing-caches-page-cached-sites-are-still-not-updated)

Answer (score 1):

try `ctrl+shift+delete` on browser to clear `cache`.

To perform caching  `config.action_controller.perform_caching` should be set to **true**

before update you must do something like  `expire_page :action => action_name`

Ex:

```
  def update
       expire_page :action => profile
       ...........
  end
```

I gathered information about caching at 2 places other day. Check them [here](http://www.codelearn.org/blog/rails-cache-with-examples) and [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html)

Comment: I don't wanna use cache. But it is still valid on my app. So, how can I solve this?

Comment: any translations are added in your app?